# Laravel Eloquent Update Affected Rows count always 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. The problem I'm facing is,

> When I tried to update a column in table with same data using laravel
>   eloquent the affected rows gives me always 1.

Here it is the query running when I run update:

```
update `table` set `updating_column` = 1, `updated_at` = 2016-09-17 15:56:53;
```

In the above query laravel updating `updated_at` column along with the column i requested to update.

Thats why I am getting 1 row affected always.

Is there any way to get actual affected rows with out `updated_at` column.

EDIT:

```
$modelobj = new Model();
$aftcnt = $modelobj->where(['ssnid'=>Session::get('SSNID')])
                   ->update([updating_column'=>1]);
```

The variable `$aftcnt` gives me 1 when i refresh the page always.

Comment: I don't think that's the cause of issue. Can you post your code which is updating the table. I can't see any condition

Comment: See edited section @jaysingkar

Comment: that's probably because you must be having only value with the specific session id. How many entries do you get with `$modelobj->where(['ssnid'=>Session::get('SSNID')])->count()`

Comment: The table contains only 3 records and with that SSNID has only 1 record.

Comment: exactly.. that's why you are getting 1 row affected as you are selecting only one row. What you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: updating_column value has already 1 and i'm again updating with 1 so the affected rows must be 0 because there is nothing to update.

Comment: `update` doesn't check in advance of the write to the database hence why the affected rows is always returned as 1. I think your most reliable option is to do a query before you do the update operation to work out how many rows are going to be changed by your update. Plus the row is always affected since `updated_at` is changed.

Comment: When i run this query `update `table` set oes_prg_st=1 where updating_column='7f473cf72e4d2f168235c73bd28482b3'` in phpmyadmin it gives me affected rows 0. but in laravel i'm getting 1. Whats going on in laravel? is my question.

Comment: @marcus.ramsden what ur saying is i need  to run a select with same where condition and the result count would be the affected rows count.

Answer (score 2):

**For Laravel 5**

You may see the example for getting affected row

```
$ids=[10,20,30,40];

$affectedRow=DB::update('update users set is_archive = 1, status=0 where id != ?', $ids);

echo $affectedRow;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already noted MySQL is reporting that there is 1 row affected because the row is "touched" meaning that the timestamps are updated. You can solve your problem in the following ways;

Run a query before you do the update:

```
$aftcnt = $modelobj->where('ssnid', Session::get('SSNID'))
    ->whereNot('updating_column', 1)->count();
```

Run update with touch disabled:

```
$modelobj->where(['ssnid'=>Session::get('SSNID')])
    ->update(['updating_column'=>1], ['touch' => false]);
```

When you disable the touch it won't try to change the timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add condition which row force to update by addding where condition

```
`updating_column` = 0;
```

like this

```
update `table` set `updating_column` = 1, `updated_at` = `2016-09-17 15:56:53` where `updating_column` = 0;
```

example

```
$modelobj = new Model();
$aftcnt = $modelobj->where(
              [
                'ssnid' => Session::get('SSNID'), 
                'updating_column' => 0
              ])
               ->update(['updating_column' => 1]);
```